# How to combine multiple states with onpress?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a react-native app. And I want to toggle two icons(downcircle and upcircle). But the onpress triggers already a  usestate. So how to combine two use states? So the default state is the icon up. But when you trigger the onPress again the icon down has to be shown.

this code I try to run:

```
    const { toggle, showAccordion } = useContext(ToggleContext);
    const { toggleIcon, setToggleIcon } = useState(false);
    const { accordionItems } = useContext(AccordionItemsContext);

    const handleClick = () => {
        setToggleIcon(!toggleIcon);
    };

    const handleSearch = (query) => {
        setSearchAnimal(query);
    };

<View>
                                {!item.hasOwnProperty("animals") && (
                                    <ButtonDetail
                                        onPress={() => {
                                            toggle(item.id);
                                            handleClick;
                                        }}>
                                        {toggleIcon ? (
                                            <AntDesign name="downcircle" size={17} color="green" />
                                        ) : (
                                            <AntDesign name="upcircle" size={17} color="green" />
                                        )}
                                    </ButtonDetail>
                                )}
                            </View>
```

ButtonDetail:

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import styled from "styled-components/native";

export const ButtonDetail = styled(TouchableOpacity)`
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    bottom: 10px;
`;
```

And when I do it like above. I get this error:

```
TypeError: setToggleIcon is not a function. (In 'setToggleIcon(!toggleIcon)', 'setToggleIcon' is undefined)
```

Question: how to toggle two icons?

Comment: You want to toggle downcircle to upcircle and at the same time upcircle to downcircle?

Comment: @AhmadZahid. default state is up. And when user triggers the icon again then the down icon has to be shown.

Comment: kindly share code for ButtonDetail component

Comment: You are destructing the useState for setToggleIcon incorrectly. useState returns an array with two items in it not an object. so your code should be [toggleIcon, setToggleIcon] instead of {toggleIcon , setToggleIcon}

Comment: ahhh, of course, This is stupid from my side. Thank you! Yes, that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error text says what the problem is - not exactly what is expected is transmitted to *onPress*. To fix this error you need to fix the code by rewriting it as follows:

```
//...
<ButtonDetail onPress={() => {
  toggle(item.id);
  handleClick();
}}>
//...
```

*onPress* should not (and cannot) accept an array inside itself, it accepts a function in which you can describe all the behavior you need that will occur when you click on an element

Comment: #Alexey Shirko.Thank you for your help. See updated post.